# gnome glyph display issues after upgrade to 23.04

Tags: gnome

[image: icons too large]

The icons/glyphs in the quicksettings thing are waay too large. Same problem is on the login screen.

I'm prepared to bet I have some local config causing this. Similar stuff has happened in the past.

Any idea what I should delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit brute force, but I deleted `~/.config/dconf/user` and logged in again and everything looked predictable again.

[image: new look]

(dark theme now, but you can see the difference)

The down side was that a bunch of my other settings, including favourites in the dock, were reset too.

But it only took a minute browsing through the settings app to get things more or less how they were.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I deleted the directory and rebooted and still got the same issue. Did you do anything special when deleting the directory? Were you running gnome at the time?

Comment: "user" is a file, not a directory. But no, I didn't do anything special. I was running Gnome at the time.

Perhaps you have some other config floating around. I wonder if Gnome still uses ~/.gconf for anything?